# Setting the background using styles

Tags: java, android, background, styles

How to set layout  drawable background using styles.xml?  In the layout I'm using 2 drawable buttons.

When I using this in styles.xml all buttons change the background to what is in styles, but I want to change only the layout background.

```
<style name="menutheme">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/menu</item>
</style>
```

My layout:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:theme="@style/menutheme"
android:contentDescription="@null"
tools:context="com.example.user.app.Activity2">


<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="312dp"
    android:layout_height="371dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.955">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/entrycity"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:background="@drawable/oval3"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ultra"
        android:text="@string/wybor2"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="59dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="334dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="243dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/entrycity"
        android:background="@drawable/oval"
        android:fontFamily="@font/ultra"
        android:text="@string/wybor"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="71dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="227dp" />

        </RelativeLayout
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try `WindowBackground` instead of background. Like,

```
<style name="menutheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/menu</item>
</style>
```

and you need to apply this theme to **acivity in manifest.** not in layout.

Comment: I want to set different background for each layout

Comment: so why you using theme to give background ? apply background to layout directly.